# Storing Apache web server's SSL certificate in HashiCorp Vault

Tags: tls, apache, hashicorp-vault

This could be basic question as I'm new to this area. I have an apache web server which load balances to a set of servers to provide a web site. The apache server has SSL enabled and we terminate TLS on load balancer level. The TLS certificates lives inside the apache server's local storage. Now our target is to use some key management solution to store the TLS certificates and private keys. We choose HashiCorp vault since it's being open sourced. The following is our mechanism to achieve this. I wanted to know if the following mentioned methods have any security concerns or issues that I need to aware and research more.

1. Use Vault PKI engine to store certificate and configure CA so the vault can get new certificate (automate getting TLS certificate from CA)
2. Define TTL for certificates
3. Use vault client to get a certificate to apache web server machine local storage
4. User retrieved certificate on apache web server

I could not found any other solution beside this. When regarding cost for new certificate I do not hope the TTL for certificate would not change with current values (maybe 1 or 2 year, I do not know the exact time). With vault introduction we only get automating the certificate request process and easiness of revoking the validity of a certificate. This seems not a enough benefit to move to vault, given we need to run at least 5 vault servers to achieve HA. Am I not using the vault correctly here?